# amcharts maps - maintain user's zoom level after update

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using amCharts map to show markers (objects) on a map. These objects are moving all the time due to longitude and latitude changes, so I'm calling `validateData()` every 4 seconds to update the map with the objects' new locations.

[Items on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTDvl.png)

The problem is that after the user zooms in, the `validateData()` call redraws the map and zooms back out. How can I redraw my map while keeping the same zoom level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the map's current zoomLevel, zoomLongitude and zoomLatitude in your map's dataProvider before you call validateData. Here's a snippet from [a demo on AmCharts' website](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/retaining-map-zoom-level-position-data-update/) that does precisely that:

```
  // set same zoom levels to retain map position/zoom
  map.dataProvider.zoomLevel = map.zoomLevel();
  map.dataProvider.zoomLatitude = map.dataProvider.zoomLatitude = map.zoomLatitude();
  map.dataProvider.zoomLongitude = map.dataProvider.zoomLongitude = map.zoomLongitude();
  // update map
  map.validateData();
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I've missed that from the docs. Your solution works like a charm !

Comment: How to fix it afterwards? It breaks backgroundZoomsToTop after called

Answer (score 0):

actually this code was taken from official examples from amcharts website, but there is a mistake in the code which makes map zoom not slowly, it "jumps" to center of the map and then zoom in to the selected country. the solution is below

```
  map.dataProvider.zoomLevel = map.zoomLevel();
  map.dataProvider.zoomLatitude = map.dataProvider.zoomLatitudeC = map.zoomLatitude();
  map.dataProvider.zoomLongitude = map.dataProvider.zoomLongitudeC = map.zoomLongitude();

  // update map
  map.validateData();
```